# How to configure tomcat to use different ports for different endpoints in a single application?

Tags: java, spring, apache, tomcat

I have a tomcat `.war` application that has a number of endpoints. Let's say they are:

```
http://myapp.com/myapp/endpoint.a
http://myapp.com/myapp/endpoint.b
```

I want `http://myapp.com/myapp/endpoint.a` to be available over port `80`, and `http://myapp.com:8080/myapp/endpoint.b` to *only* be available over port `8080`.

I can't have apache in front of tomcat, and it is unacceptable for `/myapp/endpoint.b` to be accessible on the same port as `/myapp/endpoint.a`.

Splitting the endpoints into different application contexts is also not possible.

### So far:

- Spring boot allows setting the management endpoint to be accessible on a different port but we're not using springboot and I'm not sure at what level it achieves this. http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-monitoring.html#production-ready-customizing-management-server-address
- I've been looking at the tomcat connector docs https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html but they all seem to connect a port/protocol to an *entire* application and do not allow specific endpoints, e.g. `use only port:8080 for *.b`
- It's possible to achieve this with apache and JKMount by allowing everything on port `8080` in tomcat, and then forwarding `*.a*` from `80` to `8080` in apache. But as I said a requirement is to not use apache.
- I am using spring if this helps.

Answer (score 3):

It is solvable at the application level with a combination of:

- A custom `PortAuthorisationFilter` configured in `web.xml` with a filter-mapping of the endpoints we want to restrict:

`<url-pattern>*.b</url-pattern>`

- Inside the filter we check `ServletRequest.getLocalPort()` is equal to `:8080` and reject the request otherwise. This method claims to be the port used in the TCP connection so cannot be spoofed.

At the tomcat level, we have `http` connectors at ports `80` and `8080`, that apply to the entire application.

Comment: This is a very nice answer (+1). I wonder if it fulfills the requirements completely, in that both "endpoints" are "available" (e.g. HTTP connections are accepted) on both ports with this solution. The good thing is you'll be able to send a HTTP Forbidden error code (or something alike), but the "endpoint" is listening nonetheless.

Comment: Yes I would have preferred to reject the TCP connection entirely with a Tomcat Connector but this will do the job well enough.